# Como pegar hora do sistema e guardar em uma variável?

Tags: c++

Como pegar a hora atual e guardar em uma variável em c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Data atual do sistema é: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para apenas "guardar" o jeito C++ atual de fazer é

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
...
...
auto now = system_clock::now();
```

Para trabalhar com essa nova infraestrura é um pouco mais complicado, primeiro porque ainda não existe muita experiência, e segundo porque ainda existem algumas deficiências no próprio padrão, o que acarreta a necessidade de se valer da infraestrutura subjacente em C quando é necessário exibir informações sobre tempo.

Um programinha para mostrar data e hora atuais:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip> // para put_time

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
   auto now = system_clock::now();
   time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(now); // poderia ser auto t = ...
   cout << put_time(localtime(&t), "%c") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) para retornar as informações de data e hora atual e [`localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) para representar os valores de acordo com o fuso horário local.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  time_t timer;
  struct tm *horarioLocal;

  time(&timer); // Obtem informações de data e hora
  horarioLocal = localtime(&timer); // Converte a hora atual para a hora local

  int dia = horarioLocal->tm_mday;
  int mes = horarioLocal->tm_mon + 1;
  int ano = horarioLocal->tm_year + 1900;

  int hora = horarioLocal->tm_hour;
  int min  = horarioLocal->tm_min;
  int sec  = horarioLocal->tm_sec;

  cout << "Horário: " << hora << ":" << min << ":" << sec << endl;
  cout << "Data: "    << dia  << "/" << mes << "/" << ano << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Lv1ufO)</kbd>

Para colocar o horário em uma *string*, use o [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/):

```
// C++11
std::string horario = std::to_string(hora) + ":" + std::to_string(min) + ":" + std::to_string(sec);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <time.h>

int main(){
struct tm *data_hora_atual;
time_t t = time(NULL);//inicializa a variável time com os segundos até o momento da execução
data_hora_atual = localtime(&t);
printf ("%s", asctime (data_hora_atual) );

return 0;
}
```